# Redirect to login on session or cookie timeout with iframes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iframe, cookies, owin

I'm using MVC5 and OWIN on top of an older application that was developed with ASPX pages.

I'm using an Application Cookie, and that expiry seems to work fine, and using `<Authorize>` attribute on my MVC controllers protects them just fine. However, I also have a session timeout to handle.

Unfortunately the application is using iframes, and when I have a session timeout or a cookie timeout, only the given frame that was accessing a protected resource redirects to the login page. Essentially, I get the login page inside one of the iframes instead of redirecting the whole site to the login page.

Is there some standard way of handling these timeouts (either cookie or session) so as to redirect the whole browser to the login page instead of just one iframe?